# ViewData with DropDown

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I'm using MVC3/Razor and want to bind a `DropDownList` with some data like below,

```
 @Html.DropDownList("SearchBy", new[] {     new SelectListItem { Text = "Order ID", Value = "OrdId" }, 
                                            new SelectListItem { Text = "Mobile Number", Value = "MobileNum" }, 
                                            new SelectListItem { Text = "Clerk Name", Value = "ClerkName" },
                                            new SelectListItem { Text = "Pin Number", Value = "PinNum" },
                                            new SelectListItem { Text = "RTS PayGo Ref ID", Value = "RefId" } })
```

The above code bind the `DropDownList` with respected data. Currently "Order ID" is default selected.

If user do a post action, I'm able to send the selected value to my controller.

How can we set that value to ViewData/ViewBag, so that selection of `DropDownList` will persist after postback?

Comment: Can't you store the selected value in the (view)model instead of the ViewBag? Otherwise; in the [HttpPost] method, you can add the selected value to the ViewBag and return a view.

Comment: how can we add selected item value into viewdata, below line won't run for me....@Html.DropDownList("Years", new SelectList(ViewBag.Years as System.Collections.IEnumerable, ViewData["SELECTED_VALUE"] ?? "2010"))

Comment: In your post method; you're able to get the selected value, (as you wrote). In that method, you can do ViewBag.SelectedItem = [SELECTEDITEM]

Answer (score 1):

On every action post, you'd have to continually add the item to the ViewBag or ViewData and manually keep updating it, or store it in session.  Everytime you reload the view, you have to set the selected value to match.

HTH.

Comment: In my experience this is true unless you want to get into JSON serialization and have jQuery build the dropdown options from a serialized collection in a hidden variable on load; that gets complicated and annoying quick.